# Calculating the volume of a rectangular hole with sloping edges

Tags: integration, trigonometry, volume

I need some help calculating the volume of a hole. The bottom of the hole is a rectangle which will have the measurements 15 by 35 meters. The depth is 8 meters. Now here is the tricky part. All four sides will slope with an angle of 27°.

It will look something like the green part of this inverted pyramid: http://thumbs.dreamstime.com/z/inverted-pyramid-segments-shows-hierarchy-24615808.jpg

The difference though is that if I extend the sides it will not be a pyramid but more lika a tent with shorter "roof" than bottom. (couldn't find a good image of exact shape)

My first thought was that I could use integration but my experience with them are limited. The problems I've solved has been quite straight forward. I'm guessing that I need to start with the bottom area and integrate it piece by piece (dx). What I think I am lacking is the ratio between each piece to make that integration. How do I find that?

The other option could be finding where the lines intersect at the top of the triangle and then subtract the top part. The problem is that it is not a pyramid so I just don't know where to start.

Anyone that could give me a little bit of help with this one?

(I have english as a second language so some words might be are wrong.)

Comment: You need to find the volume of all the pyramid and than the pyramid that does not include the green part. Let me know if you have problem with this.

Comment: If you cut out the middle (the triangular prism part) of a tent, you will be left with a pyramid.

Answer (score 1):

The statute of limitations may have passed on this stale question, but I believe the correct answer  can be found by noting that since the partial derivatives of the sloping sides satisfy $z_x=z_y = m=\tan 27^{\circ}$, it follows that as we climb upward from th bottom of the hole, the  $x$ and $y$ dimensions of the rectangular cross-sections increase at equal constant rates: $dx/dz=  dy/dz= 2m'$ where $m'= 1/m$.  (The factor 2 occurs because the rectangle has  two parallel sides in each direction). Thus the area of the cross-sectional rectangle at height $z$  (measured from bottom of hole)  is $A(z)=(15+2zm')\times (35+ (2zm')$

Then volume =$\int_{z=0}^{z=8} A(z) dz$=13109.9

Comment: I think this is how the problem was meant to be solved. I get the same result by geometry.

Answer (score 0):

We begin by finding the dimensions of the top face of the frustum (the geometric name of the hole you described). We see that both the top width and top breadth are $\frac{16}{\tan(27^\circ)}$ larger than the frustum's bottom width and bottom breadth. Thus, the top has dimensions of $15 + \frac{16}{\tan(27^\circ)}$ by $35 + \frac{16}{\tan(27^\circ)}.$

Now we wish to find the height of the pyramid that the frustum shares a top face with. Using the values we just found, we can see that this pyramid's height is $8 + \frac{15\tan(27^\circ)}{2}.$ We can now subtract the smaller pyramid from the larger one to find the volume of the solid. The smaller pyramid has volume $V_{s} = (\frac{1}{3})(15)(35)(\frac{15\tan(27^\circ)}{2}).$ The larger pyramid has volume $V_{l} = (\frac{1}{3})(15 + \frac{16}{\tan(27*)})(35 + \frac{16}{\tan(27^\circ)})(8 + \frac{15\tan(27^\circ)}{2}).$

The volume of the frustum (hole) is $V_{l} - V_{s},$ which is approximately $11472$ cubic meters.

Comment: OP correctly pointed out that the shape in the question is **not** a frustum of a pyramid. This answer is simply incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

If the sides of the hole make an angle of exactly $27^\circ$ with the plane in which the bottom of the hold lies (that is, if each surface rises $\tan(27^\circ)$ meters for each meter of horizontal distance in its steepest direction), the top of the hole will have dimensions $15 + 2(8\cot(27^\circ)) \approx 46.401768$
by $35 + 2(8\cot(27^\circ)) \approx 66.401768$, measured in meters.

If we then make four vertical slices through the hole, each one a plane passing through one side of the rectangle on the bottom, we will cut the hole into one rectangular prism, four triangular prisms, and four inverted square pyramids.

The volume of the rectangular prism is $15\times35\times8 = 4200$.

Each triangular prism has vertical triangular bases that are right triangles with legs of $8$ and $8\cot(27^\circ) \approx 15.700884$.
The volume of each of the two smaller triangular prisms is therefore
$\frac12 \times 8 \times 8\cot(27^\circ) \times 15 \approx 942.053$
and the volume of each of the two larger triangular prisms is
$\frac12 \times 8 \times 8\cot(27^\circ) \times 35 \approx 2198.124$.

Each pyramid has base area $(8\cot(27^\circ))^2$, height $8$, and volume
$\frac13 \times (8\cot(27^\circ))^2 \times 8 \approx 657.381$.

Putting all nine pieces together, we get
$$
15\times35\times8
 + 2\left(\frac12 \times 8 \times 8\cot(27^\circ) \times 15\right)
 + 2\left(\frac12 \times 8 \times 8\cot(27^\circ) \times 35\right)
 + 4\left(\frac13 \times (8\cot(27^\circ))^2 \times 8\right) \approx 13109.876,
$$
thereby verifying [another answer that used actual integration](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4707866/139123).

The angle $27^\circ$, however, is suspiciously close to $\arctan\left(\frac12\right)$.
In fact, it's the closest whole-degree angle.
This makes me suspect that the slopes of the sides of the hole were meant to be
$\arctan\left(\frac12\right)$ rather than exactly $27^\circ$.
If that is true, instead of writing $8\cot(27^\circ)$ we can just write $16$,
so the top of the hole will have dimensions $47$ by $67$.
The volume of each smaller triangular prism then is $960$,
each larger triangular prism is $2240$,
and the volume of each pyramid is $\frac{2048}{3}$.
The total is
$$
4200 + 2\times960 + 2\times2240 + 4 \times \frac{2048}{3} = \frac{39992}{3}
\approx 13330.667. 
$$

If the sides actually make angles of $27^\circ$ (or $\arctan\left(\frac12\right)$)
with vertical planes rather than with a horizontal plane,
the top of the hole is only $23$ meters by $43$ meters and the volume is much smaller than calculated above.